# Unable to open "...\file.vmdk". The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

When I want to open my virtual machine, I get the error that the system cannot find a .vmdk file, but it exists as you can see in the below image. This error occurs since yesterday, but before I was able to open it. What happened and how could I solve it? [This topic](https://superuser.com/questions/1470149/vmware-workstation-error-unable-to-open-file-x-vmdk-the-system-cannot-f) couldn't help me.

[image]